# How to have a list of all the object type created in a ruby script

Tags: ruby

I want to find a list/sum up of the class that are created in a ruby script at run time.

I do this

```
# rewrite class in order to display ClassName when GCed"
#
$objs = []
class Class
  alias oldNew  new
  def new(*args)
    inst =  oldNew(*args)
    $objs << inst.class.name unless $objs.include?(inst.class.name)
    inst
  end
end
# some code
puts $bjs
```

Is there a better way to do this?

I have tried to use :

```
$objs = []
class Class
  alias oldNew  new
  def new(*args)
    inst =  oldNew(*args)
    ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(inst, proc {|id| puts "Finalizer one on #{id.name}" })
    inst
  end
end
```

But I have no output .

FYI some of my code that I test use a C extension.

**Edit**
More specific code:

```
require "gtk3"
require "objspace"


$objs = []
class Class
  alias oldNew  new
  def new(*args)
    inst =  oldNew(*args)
    # This doesn't work
    # ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(inst, proc {|id| puts "Finalizer one on #{id.name}" })
    $objs << inst.class.name unless $objs.include?(inst.class.name)
    inst
  end
end

TITLE_COLUMN = 0
AUTHOR_COLUMN = 1
CHECKED_COLUMN = 2

model = Gtk::TreeStore.new(String, String, TrueClass)
iter = model.append(nil)
iter[TITLE_COLUMN] = "The Principle of Reason"
iter[AUTHOR_COLUMN] = "Martin Heidegger"
iter[CHECKED_COLUMN] = false

iter = model.append(nil)
iter.set_values(["The Art of Computer Programming", "Donald E. Knuth", true])

# append child
child_iter = model.append(iter)
child_iter[TITLE_COLUMN] = "Volume 1: Fundamental Algorithms"

# append another child
child_iter = model.append(iter)
child_iter.set_value(TITLE_COLUMN, "Volume 2: Seminumerical Algorithms")
child_iter.set_value(CHECKED_COLUMN, true)

# append another child
child_iter = model.append(iter)
child_iter.set_values(["Volume 3: Sorting and Searching", "Donald E. Knuth", true])

def treeview_widget_of(model)
  treeview = Gtk::TreeView.new(model)
  treeview.append_column(Gtk::TreeViewColumn.new("Title", Gtk::CellRendererText.new, { :text => TITLE_COLUMN }))
  treeview.append_column(Gtk::TreeViewColumn.new("Author", Gtk::CellRendererText.new, { :text => AUTHOR_COLUMN }))
  treeview.append_column(Gtk::TreeViewColumn.new("Author", Gtk::CellRendererToggle.new, { :active => CHECKED_COLUMN }))
  treeview
end

def display_model(model)
  win = Gtk::Window.new(:toplevel)
  win.title = "Simple Gtk::TreeStore"
  win.add(treeview_widget_of(model))
  win.show_all
  win.signal_connect("destroy") { Gtk.main_quit }
  Gtk.main
end

display_model(model)
puts $objs.inspect
```

**edit 2**

```
["Gio::Loader", "Class", "Module", "GObjectIntrospection::TypeTag", "GObjectIntrospection::Direction", "GObjectIntrospection::FieldInfoFlags", "GObjectIntrospection::ScopeType", nil, "LoadError", "Gdk::Loader", "Gtk::Loader", "Gtk::TreeStore", "GLib::Value", "Gtk::Window", "Gtk::TreeView", "Gtk::CellRendererText", "Gtk::TreeViewColumn", "Gtk::CellRendererToggle"]
```

Comment: Can you give some examples, i.e. fill in `#some code` with some code?

Comment: Of course. See the edit part

Comment: What is your question? The code that you shared has some output - whats wrong with that output and what is your expected output.

Comment: My question is the only sentence with a "?". Which is : "s there a better way to do this?". If no, there will be a more complicated question but I want to work by step.

Comment: Is the output in **edit 2** actually the expected output? For example, it doesn't include `String` or `Array` but on the other hand, it includes the singleton object `nil`.

Comment: That is the problem, That is why I tried to see if it is the best way to get the Classes of the objects that are created when I run the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a variation of the code snippets in [Jörg W Mittag's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992547/how-to-have-a-list-of-all-the-object-type-created-in-a-ruby-script#comment57714072_34992886):

```
require 'objspace'
def monitor_classes
  b = []
  a = []
  ObjectSpace.each_object { |o| a << o.__id__ }
  yield
  ObjectSpace.each_object { |o| b << o.__id__ }
  (b - a).map { |id| ObjectSpace._id2ref(id).class }.uniq
end

monitor_classes do
  'str'
end
#=> [String]

monitor_classes do
  []
end
#=> [Array]

monitor_classes do
  {}
end
#=> [Hash]

monitor_classes do
  loop
end
#=> [Enumerator]
```

Comment: I like your answer but with it I am still having the same problem try :  puts -(monitor_classes {a = "toto"; b=a.size}).inspect . It returns [String] but b is a number and it doesnt appear.

Comment: @cedlemo unlike other objects, Ruby does not *create* `Fixnum` objects. They have immediate value and therefore, `ObjectSpace` can't track them.

Comment: Is it the same thing when this line in my example iter = model.append(nil) is executed ? The variable model is a Gtk::TreeStore instance and iter is a Gtk::TreeIter instance but I am not able to track it existance/creation.

Comment: That's unlikely, `Gtk::TreeStore` and `Gtk::TreeStore` look like usual classes.

Comment: Have you more infos on immediate value in ruby (links source ?)

Comment: The documentation for [`ObjectSpace#each_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-each_object) says: *"Immediate objects (Fixnums, Symbols true, false, and nil) are never returned."*. You might also check out the documentation for [`Fixnum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Fixnum.html), [`Symbol`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Symbol.html), [`TrueClass`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/TrueClass.html), [`FalseClass`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/FalseClass.html) and [`NilClass`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/NilClass.html)

Answer (score 4):

This is really simple:

```
require 'objspace'

ObjectSpace.each_object(Class)
```

Note, however, that this will only get you the *classes*, and *not* the types. The types of an object are the protocols it speaks, but there is no representation of this in the Ruby language, it's all in the programmer's head.

For example, there is a type that I will call `Appendable`, which is characterized by an object responding to `<<` with `self` and as a side-effect adding the argument to its internal state. Arrays and Strings are both `Appendable`, even though they don't share any common ancestor class except `Object`. Also note that even though `Integer` responds to `<<`, it is not `Appendable`.

There is another type I will call `Iterable`, which is characterized by an object responding to `each` with `self` and as a side-effect `yield`ing its elements to the block. The `Enumerable` mixin depends on this type, but there is no way to express this dependency in Ruby, it has to be stated externally in the documentation, or in this particular case, it is just common knowledge that is deeply ingrained in the Ruby community.

Comment: You code will enumerate all classes, not just the ones created by the script (whatever that means in particular).

Comment: Well, the question says "in" a script, not "by" a script. I interpreted that to mean the classes that get created as a result of running the script, i.e. the classes that exist at the end of the script. But yours is a valid interpretation, too. The difference between the two interpretations is basically just `existing = ObjectSpace.each_object(Class)` at the beginning of the script and then `existing.to_a - ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).to_a` at the end.

Comment: It also says *"at run time"*, but that can interpreted either way, too ;-)